# XML deserialization with parent object reference

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file describing a website. It consists of the Site as the root node that can have Pages, Pages can have Objects such as Button or TextBox and Dialogs. Dialogs can also have Objects.

In the corresponding C# classes, all is derived from Element. When I deserialize the XML, how can I have a reference to the Parent of the element getting constructed?

I was told complex types can't de deserialized that way but if I add an ID field to each element in the XML then the parent can be referenced using that and hence be deserialized properly. How would I implement that? I wouldn't want to manually add an ID field to each element in the XML file...

My element class:

```
public class Element 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string XPath { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Site", Type = typeof(Site))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Page", Type = typeof(Page))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Dialog", Type = typeof(Dialog))]
    public Element Parent { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Children", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Page))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Button))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Dialog))]
    public Collection<Element> Children { get; set; }

}
```

My deserialization:

```
public Site GetSiteFromXml(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Site));
    return serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName))) as Site;
}
```

My XML file:

```
<Site>
  <Name>WebSiteName</Name>
  <Url>https://site.url</Url>
  <Children>
    <Page>
      <Name>HomePage</Name>
      <Address>#page=1</Address>
      <Children>
        <Button>
          <Name>LoginDialogButton</Name>
          <Id>LoginIcon</Id>
          <XPath>//*[@id="LoginIcon"]</XPath>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <Action>OpenLoginDialog</Action>
        </Button>
        <Dialog>
          <Name>LoginPopUpDialog</Name>
          <Id>loginModal</Id>
          <Children>
            <TextBox>
              <Name>UserNameInput</Name>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBox>
              <Name>PasswordInput</Name>
            </TextBox>
            <Button>
              <Name>LoginButton</Name>
              <Action>DialogDismiss</Action>
            </Button>
          </Children>
        </Dialog>
      </Children>
    </Page>
  </Children>
</Site>
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823399/maintaining-xml-hierarchy-ie-parent-child-information-in-objects-generated-by

Comment: Kind of related but in that case the Parent and Child objects are different classes. In mine, they are the same. I saw the article yesterday and was trying to make it work for me but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any mechanism in place to guarantee that the `Parent` and `Children` properties stay in sync, the easiest way to do this is to tell `XmlSerializer` to ignore both properties, and add a proxy property that returns the list of children as an array (not a collection).  Inside the *setter* for the proxy property, populate the `Children` collection and also set the `Parent` property of the each child:

```
public class Element
{
    public Element() { Children = new Collection<Element>(); }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string XPath { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Element Parent { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Collection<Element> Children { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Children", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Page))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Button))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Dialog))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Site))]
    public Element[] ChildArrayCopy
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            Children.Clear();
            if (value != null)
                foreach (var child in value)
                    child.SetParent(this);
        }
    }
}

public static class ElementExtensions
{
    public static void SetParent(this Element child, Element parent)
    {
        if (child == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (child.Parent == parent)
            return; // Nothing to do.
        if (child.Parent != null)
            child.Parent.Children.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = parent;
        if (parent != null)
            parent.Children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Your XML can now be deserialized and serialized successfully.

Incidentally, I would consider replacing your `public Collection<Element> Children { get; set; }` with `public ReadOnlyCollection<Element> Children { get; }`.  Then keep the children in a private list, and return `list.AsReadOnly()`.  Having done so, you can now guarantee the child list stays up-to-date in the `Parent` setter:

```
public class Element
{

    public Element() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string XPath { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Element> children = new List<Element>();
    private Element parent = null;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Element Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return parent;
        }
        set
        {
            if (parent == value)
                return;
            if (parent != null)
                parent.children.Remove(this);
            parent = value;
            if (parent != null)
                parent.children.Add(this);
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Element> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return children.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("Children", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(TextBox))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Page))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Button))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Dialog))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Site))]
    public Element[] ChildArrayCopy
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                foreach (var child in value)
                    child.Parent = this;
        }
    }
}
```