# Adding the Parent id to Serialization as Object class

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have the following XML file which I am using the VSC#(windows forms) code to save it as a class:

```
<Steps >
  <Step id ="1" Name="S1">
    <Step id ="2" Name="S11">
      <Step id ="3" Name="S111" />
      <Step id ="4" Name="S112" />
        <Step id ="5" Name="S1121" />
    </Step >
    <Step id ="6" Name="S12" />
  </Step >
</Steps >
```

The code I wrote as:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Steps
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Step")]
    public List<Step> Step { get; set; }
}
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Step
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Step")]
    public List<Step> Step1 { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I get the `ParentID` into the child field for
   children?(there would be only `null` for node with `id=1`, otherwise
   each child has its parents id)
2. The second question is that after coding in object class, how could
   I insert a desired child with giving the id name? For example, I
   would like to insert a child with `id=4C`  and `name=S112C` after
   node with `id=4`?

**Update:**(after answering both question)

Let's we assume that I want to create a new field as `Hierarchy` in the `Step` which takes values of string created/given by user

```
Step.Hierarchy = // some strings ;
```

It means I want to replace it with `ParentId`. The reason is that because sometimes there are some situations which I should insert two empty nodes/components(There is no name and Id for it, as below) as a child for some steps

```
steps.Add(new Step { Id = " ", Name = " " }, "4");
```

where one empty node will be child of other one. Then I will have difficulty for giving `PrentId` reference for the second node(child to the above node).

```
steps.Add(new Step { Id = " ", Name = " " }, " ");
```

This is why I want to create a virtual field like `Hierarchy` to assign an arbitrary value to it and refer `ParentId` to it instead of `Id`. Then each Step has a non `null` reference.

If you have an idea that would be thankful!!

Comment: @dbc thanks a lot for your comment and answer! In the second question I mean inserting a Step into the Step hierarchy by searching for a given Step class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I ensure that `child.ParentId` always equals `parent.Id` after deserializing?**

The natural approach to setting `Step.ParentId` after deserialization would be to do so in an [`OnDeserialized`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) event.  Unfortunately, [`XmlSerializer` does not support deserialization events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266547/how-do-you-find-out-when-youve-been-loaded-via-xml-serialization).  Given that, you may need to investigate an alternate design.

One possibility is to replace your `List<Step>` with a custom collection that *automatically* maintains the `ParentId` reference when a child is added to a parent, along the lines of [Maintaining xml hierarchy (ie parent-child) information in objects generated by XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823399/maintaining-xml-hierarchy-ie-parent-child-information-in-objects-generated-by).  Unfortunately, `ObservableCollection` is not suitable for this purpose, because [the list of old items is not included in the notification event when it is cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224155/when-clearing-an-observablecollection-there-are-no-items-in-e-olditems).  However, it's quite easy to make our own by subclassing [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx).

Thus, your object model would become the following.  Note that I have modified some of your property names to follow [c# naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Steps
{
    readonly ChildCollection<Step> steps;

    public Steps()
    {
        this.steps = new ChildCollection<Step>();
        this.steps.ChildAdded += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Item != null)
                e.Item.ParentId = null;
        };
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Step")]
    public Collection<Step> StepList { get { return steps; } }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Step
{
    readonly ChildCollection<Step> steps;

    public Step()
    {
        this.steps = new ChildCollection<Step>();
        this.steps.ChildAdded += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Item != null)
                e.Item.ParentId = this.Id;
        };
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Step")]
    public Collection<Step> StepList { get { return steps; } }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("ParentID")]
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class ChildCollectionEventArgs<TChild> : EventArgs
{
    public readonly TChild Item;

    public ChildCollectionEventArgs(TChild item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
}

public class ChildCollection<TChild> : Collection<TChild>
{
    public event EventHandler<ChildCollectionEventArgs<TChild>> ChildAdded;

    public event EventHandler<ChildCollectionEventArgs<TChild>> ChildRemoved;

    void OnRemoved(TChild item)
    {
        var removed = ChildRemoved;
        if (removed != null)
            removed(this, new ChildCollectionEventArgs<TChild>(item));
    }

    void OnAdded(TChild item)
    {
        var added = ChildAdded;
        if (added != null)
            added(this, new ChildCollectionEventArgs<TChild>(item));
    }

    public ChildCollection() : base() { }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
            OnRemoved(item);
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, TChild item)
    {
        OnAdded(item);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < Count)
        {
            OnRemoved(this[index]);
        }
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, TChild item)
    {
        OnAdded(item);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Now `ParentId` will be set whenever a child is added to a parent, both after deserialzation, and in any applications code.

(If for whatever reason you *cannot* replace your `List<Step>` with a `Collection<Step>`, you could consider serializing an array proxy property and setting the `ParentId` values in the setter, along the lines of [XML deserialization with parent object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424460/xml-deserialization-with-parent-object-reference).  But I think a design that automatically sets the parent id in all situations is preferable.)

**How can I add a `Step` to a tree of `Step` objects by specifying `ParentId`?**

You could create recursive `Linq` extensions that traverse the `Step` hierarchy, along the lines of [Efficient graph traversal with LINQ - eliminating recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253161/efficient-graph-traversal-with-linq-eliminating-recursion):

```
public static class StepExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Step> TraverseSteps(this Steps root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(root.StepList, s => s.StepList);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Step> TraverseSteps(this Step root)
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(root, s => s.StepList);
    }

    public static bool TryAdd(this Steps root, Step step, string parentId)
    {
        foreach (var item in root.TraverseSteps())
            if (item != null && item.Id == parentId)
            {
                item.StepList.Add(step);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static void Add(this Steps root, Step step, string parentId)
    {
        if (!root.TryAdd(step, parentId))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Parent {0} not found", parentId));
    }
}

public static class RecursiveEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Rewritten from the answer by Eric Lippert https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert
    // to "Efficient graph traversal with LINQ - eliminating recursion" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253161/efficient-graph-traversal-with-linq-eliminating-recursion
    // to ensure items are returned in the order they are encountered.

    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
        T root,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)
    {
        yield return root;

        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        try
        {
            stack.Push((children(root) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).GetEnumerator());

            while (stack.Count != 0)
            {
                var enumerator = stack.Peek();
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    stack.Pop();
                    enumerator.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
                    stack.Push((children(enumerator.Current) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).GetEnumerator());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var enumerator in stack)
                enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> roots,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)
    {
        return from root in roots
               from item in Traverse(root, children)
               select item;
    }
}
```

Them to add a child to a specific parent by ID, you would do:

```
steps.Add(new Step { Id = "4C", Name = "S112C" }, "4");
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sx0s3S).

**Update**

If you somehow are having trouble adding [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to `Step` and `Steps` because they are nested classes, you could add `TraverseSteps()` and `Add()` as object methods:

```
public partial class Step
{
    public IEnumerable<Step> TraverseSteps()
    {
        return RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(this, s => s.StepList);
    }
}

public partial class Steps
{
    public IEnumerable<Step> TraverseSteps()
    {
        return RecursiveEnumerableExtensions.Traverse(StepList, s => s.StepList);
    }

    public bool TryAdd(Step step, string parentId)
    {
        foreach (var item in TraverseSteps())
            if (item != null && item.Id == parentId)
            {
                item.StepList.Add(step);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public void Add(Step step, string parentId)
    {
        if (!TryAdd(step, parentId))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Parent {0} not found", parentId));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an error regarding the first question. `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Collection' could not be found`. May I ask your help?

Comment: [`Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in the namespace `System.Collections.ObjectModel` so you need `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`

Comment: Sorry, I had it but there was a typo in it. By the way for the second question I have this error: `error CS1109: Extension method must be defined in a top level static class; StepExtensions is a nested class`. I put it out of main form but still I have the error

Comment: @Royeh - you must still have it nested somehow.  See [the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sx0s3S).  Or you could add `Traverse()`, `Add()` and `TryAdd()` as instance methods to `Step` and `Steps` as is shown in the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect answer. It was very keen one. May I ask for your help and idea about the Update part. I really appreciate for your time! :)

Comment: @Royeh - I would suggest you ask a second question, with a [complete example of what you need to do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The preferred format for questions here is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) - plus I'm not entirely sure I understand your requirements just from the update.

Comment: I posted as a new question. I hope I would get the answer! I really appreciate it for your helps and answers!!